# Unbiasedness of a test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, bias, statistical-power

p is the probability of success in a 
series of Bernoullian trials. To test 
H0:P= 0·5, trials are conducted and 
H0 is rejected if 7 or 8 successes  are 
observed.

If H1 is double sided, how do I comment whether the test is biased or not.
For H1:P>0.5, I found that test is unbiased and for H1:P<0.5, I found that the test is biased. So is the test biased?

Answer (score 2):

Unbiasedness has a special meaning regarding hypothesis testing. It amounts to having the power function minimized at the null value (in your case p=0.5) and is equal to the significance level of the test.  See the following reference by Richard Lockhart at Simon Fraser University:

http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~lockhart/richard/801/04_1/lectures/unbiased_tests/web.pdf.

This link is a class tutorial on unbiased tests and goes into a lot more detail. You only need to check the power function at 0.05 for both one-sided tests and the two-sided test. That will determine if the two-sided test is in fact unbiased and whether or not either of the one-sided tests is biased or not.

Note: Rejecting only if at least 7 out of the 8 samples are successes tells you what significance level you are testing at.

Comment: My answer is 3 lines and has substance.  I will edit it and add a little.

Comment: This may be homework and therefore should have the self study tag. So the OP should work out the final answer to the specific problem on his own using my hints.